# Start process immediately, without freezing application

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I need help with processes. In my application im printing receipes. And till today everytime user print it, application was frozen until receipt was printed. So I decided to use Process with background priority. And actually it works - user could use application at the same time when receipt was printed. Problem is that, I have function to relog user every X receipes print. It works like

```
if (current_receipt_index_in_DB % restart_every_X_receipt == 0) - restartApp;
```

So if current index = 20, and X = 2, it will restart every 2 receipt.

Problem is that, now, when I have process working in background which print receipt, and application need to be restarted from code - receipt doesnt print at all.

Code:

```
        PrintReceipt prRec = new PrintReceipt();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => prRec.PrintReceiptParagon(....parameters....)));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                {
                    t.Start();
                }));
```

and function to restart application:

```
    string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("myApp.exe");

    Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "myApp.exe"), "-restart " + paramID);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    foreach (Process p in procs)
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
```

Well, propably those p.Kill is not really needed, but seriously - I've tried everything and have no idea how can I make it work..

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you add a callback to your BeginInvoke and when that returns you can restart the app?

Comment: Could You please explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to make your receipt printing process another EXE. Make it a `Console` application that receives the necessary command-line arguments. When you start it:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToExe, args);
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Well, I though about it but I think I really cant do it. Im passing 5/6 parameters to printer (and if user want, adding some extra lines on receipt) so when there will be 20 items on receipt, i should pass 5/6 *20 parametrs. Maybe its not so bad idea, but I'll try to find some better solution.

Comment: @user1617141, instead of passing the parameters raw, build a file and then pass the path to the `.ini` file. That's a pretty simple workaround. Plus it means that the printing commands are in a readable format where you can review what was printed, when, and by who.

Comment: Im just wonder why that Thread doesn't start immediately. When there's no need to restart application, receipt comes right before one second. But when application need to be restarted, thread just doesn's start.. So I guess main problem is that, process is being killed before thread even start to print receipt...

Comment: @user1617141, that's right. The process is being killed before the thread can even get started.

Comment: But question is why? Isnt there  any queue for threads? First of all im clicking Pay Button, then class which print receipt should run, and after button is released restart application. Why is it working that strange way?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's possible to add bool value in class which print receipt, and when this value == true restart app then? Any idea?

Comment: @user1617141, the thread is *controlled by the process.* When the process is shut down, the thread is destroyed.

Comment: @user1617141, just make it a separate application. It's better that way. You've already defined that it's *independent of the other application.*

Comment: Well, maybe this will be strange for you, but and I dont really think I could make exe for one day.. Especially when we provide receipt print for so many devices - and for each I'll need to create one exe witch switch or separated..;/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ci1JhuF9 and again no idea why it doesn't work..  @EDIT: of course in return should be true. but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made it, but still have one little problem.

Solution:

Im creating two Threads like:

```
        t_par = new Thread(
            () =>
            {

                PrintReceipt prRec = new PrintReceipt();
                prRec.PrintReceiptParagon(--parameters--);


            });
```

second one is almost same, but running code to restart application.

And in window.loaded:

```
 if (t_par != null)
                   {
                       t_par.Start();
                       t_par.Join();


                       if (Functions.thr != null)
                       {
                           Functions.thr.Start();
                       }
                   }
```

Which runs Threads one by one - work's ok for me.

But problem for now is that, application freeze when receipt is printed (took 3/4 second from button click to complete print).

Any ideas how to 'unfreeze' GUI?

Thanks!